# android: GLWallpaperService causing green screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper

I am trying to create a live wallpaper using opengl (<2.0).

I imported and tried to run Robert Green's GLWallpaperService and Example [here](https://github.com/markfguerra/GLWallpaperExample) (using Eclipse SDK).

My phone is a Huwei Ascend Android 2.1. I already know it can run other opengl LWPs.

When I run the package, it just produces a solid green screen, and no shapes or anything.

Ive researched it alot and still cant figure out why this is happening.

I read a few times that the namespaces have to be changed to my package. But still no luck...

I tried linking his GLWallpaperService JAR library to my package as per instructed. Nope.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try gl.glScale() in your Renderer Code. I also got the same problem and i figured out that my GLView was so much zoomed that i cant see anything. try to reduce scale.
My program wo

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this on my Galaxy Nexus by adding

gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

to onSurfaceCreated in MyRenderer.java.

Answer (score 0):

The example project you linked to had bugs in the rendering code, as others here have pointed out. It has since been deprecated and deleted for maintenance\workload reasons.

However, there's currently some example wallpaper code embedded into the [main repository of GLWallpaperService](https://github.com/GLWallpaperService/GLWallpaperService). It's set up as a full Android application so developers can test using that example as needed.